# Cannot set trigger to tomorrow date using at(date) using GAS

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, triggers, google-docs-api

I want to set trigger at(Date) /*today, or tomorrow*/ doesnt work
but works for "the day after tomorrow"

```
e.g.: 2017,04,08,5,30 //not creating trigger
2017,04,09,5,30 //not creating trigger
2017,04,10,5,30 //creates trigger

mydate = new Date(year, month, day, hrs, mins);
ScriptApp.newTrigger('myfunc').timeBased().at(mydate).create();
```

Comment: The month is zero based therefore you are setting date for May.

Comment: It may be May or whatever but why the trigger is not created. May is later than April so it should have created.

Comment: My guess would be that you are overriding previous triggers when you are setting the last one as it is the only one that takes effect. Cannot say without seeing the rest of your code that calls the function.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a sample code snippet that sets a time-based trigger for tomorrow (10:30 am)

```
var date = new Date();
date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
date.setHours(10,30,0)
ScriptApp.newTrigger("myfunc").timeBased().at(date).create();
```

Comment: Thanks, one doubt you have used date.getDate()+1 which is relative to current date. How will I do it if absolute value say 12apr 2017 @ 10:30pm?